# Functions in Tkinter

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter, arguments

So I am practicing using Tkinter with python, and I am just trying to learn the basics. My code right now is

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.prompt = tk.Label(self, text="Press a button", anchor="w")
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Button 1", command = self.button1)
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Button 2", command = self.button2)
        self.output = tk.Label(self, text="")

        # lay the widgets out on the screen. 
        self.prompt.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.output.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.button1.pack(side="left")
        self.button2.pack(side="right")

    def button1(self):
        result = "You just pressed button 1."
        self.output.configure(text=result)
    def button2(self):
        result = "You just pressed button 2."
        self.output.configure(text=result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

This works fine, but I am trying to make it a little cleaner and only use one function. I tried this:

```
def button(self, string):
    result = string
    self.output.configure(text=result)
```

And on the buttons, I used

```
self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Button 1", command = self.button(
"You just pressed button 1"))
self.button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Button 2", command = self.button(
"You just pressed button 2"))
```

For some reason though, when I add the second argument to the button function, it stops working. If I use the exact same code, it works fine, but when I add a second argument I get this error:

```
line 31, in button
    self.output.configure(text=result)
AttributeError: Example instance has no attribute 'output'
```

What is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling functions with arguments on "command" and "bind"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396211/calling-functions-with-arguments-on-command-and-bind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `command` attribute expects a reference to a function. When you do `command=self.button(...)`, you are immediately calling the function and then using the result of the function as the value for the `command` attribute.

If you want to pass arguments, you need to use `lambda` or `functools.partial`. This question has been asked many times on this site. See, for example, [Calling functions with arguments on "command" and "bind"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9396211/7432) and [python Tkinter: passing an argument to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10289128/7432)